# Error during server start up after hotswap-agent configured with Tomcat and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have configured hotswap agent in eclipse(version >3.3) and tomcat(version6.0) referring the below two sites.

- http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start#
- http://tirthalpatel.blogspot.com/2014/06/steps-to-setup-hotswap-agent-in-eclipse.html

I have followed all the steps as it is but am getting below error during tomcat server start up after I add `"-XXaltjvm="dcevm" -javaagent:D:\Softwares\hotswap-agent.jar"` in tomcat VM arguments.

```
JDK version : jdk1.7.0_45

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: The specified procedure could not be found
```

Please help me to resolve this error and to use hotswap agent with Tomcat and Eclipse successfully.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the issue and here's what helped me.

1. Go to [DCEVM releases page](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/releases) and download the most recent one.
2. Make sure your JDK version matches DCEVM supported java version. [Here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) you can download archived java releases.
3. On your IDE debug configuration specify patch to JDK you've patched as JRE.
4. Specify VM arguments needed for HotSwapAgent: `-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:c:\java\hotswap-agent.jar`(use your path to agent jar).

If that doesn't work, try to have only one jdk patched.